# How to create New instance in db2 10.1 using IBM Data Studio

Tags: database, db2

How to create new instance in db2 10.1 using command line db2icrt command with example or using data studio client.

Anybody please reply.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Which OS are you usnig.

**In Lunix/UNIX/OS X**

You have two options:

- Dedicated user for the instance

You need to create one user in the OS (useradd) with a file system

```
useradd -m db2inst2
/opt/db2/10.1/instance/db2icrt -u db2inst1 db2inst1
```

- Your own user

You install DB2 in your home, and then your username will be the name of the instance (non-root installation)

**In Windows**

The command does not need a dedicated user for the instance.

Comment: Am using windows OS .. Okay I will try and create an instance.

Comment: I had created the Instance db2icrt -u db2admin db2inst1, set the db2 instance using %DB2INSTANCE to my instance and Start the DB2 instance using db2start and Create SAMPLE database using 
db2sampl

Comment: Actually I run some sqls related to my product which throws some errors - "DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0204N  "DB2ADMIN.XPSOBJECT" is an undefined name.  SQLSTATE=42704
" DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0204N  "DB2ADMIN.VERSION" is an undefined name.  SQLSTATE=42704" how to increase default buffer pool and table space page size from 4 kb to 32 kb ?

Comment: Could anybody please help me I need to Alter bufferpool with respect to number of page size from 4 kb to 32 kb

Comment: Hi, I saw different questions here. The initial question was about new instance. The comments talks about "DB2ADMIN.XPSOBJECT", but this table is not part of the sample database. And finally, you are talking about buffer pool. I advise you to create different questions for each point. BTW, the page size of a bufferpool cannot be changed.